# jQuery Mobile passing variables in url from dynamic created content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello guys I have one question...

I dynamicly create a content and inside i have an  with an url from which i want to pass two variables

```
var content =$("<div data-role='collapsible' id='set" + naslov + "'><h3>Sectionit " + naslov + "</h3><p>" + opis + "</p><a href='glavna.html#pageopis?naslov=" + naslov + "&opis=" + opis + "' class='ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all'><div class='prostor1tr'>More</div></a></div>");
```

as you se i want to pass two variables "naslov" and "opis"

```
<a href='glavna.html#pageopis?naslov=" + naslov + "&opis=" + opis + "'
```

but when i get on the other page the URL looks like this

> /glavna.html#pageopis

does anyone know why this happens ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to error in conacte string, url is broken. Its working.

```
 var content =$('<div data-role="collapsible" id="set"' + naslov + '"><h3>Sectionit ' + naslov + '</h3><p>' + opis + '</p><a data-ajax="false" href="glavna.html#pageopis?naslov='+naslov+'&opis='+opis+'" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"><div class="prostor1tr">More</div></a></div>');
```